# Nav controller en pantallas seleccionadas

Tags: ios, xcode, rápido

Quiero pedirles a la comunidad de profesionales que me puedan ayudar en un problema que presento en mi proyecto. Para empezar he creado un **NavigationController** pero para las primeras pantallas INICIO, LOGIN Y SIGNUP decidi ocultarlo desde el **View Controller**. Con el siguiente código:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

Sin embargo deseo que aparezca nuevamente el **NavigationController**  en la pantalla home pero la barra de navegación no aparece de ninguna forma que he intentado como por ejemplo...

Crear un segundo navController y no sucede nada.
Crear otro storyboard para iniciar con otro **NavigationController** y tampoco.
Aplicar la siguiente propiedad en los botones Login y Sign UP

```
 let mainStoreboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
    let DVC = mainStoreboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomesViewController") as!
    HomesViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: y tampoco.
```

Si alguien puede aportarme para progresar en mi proyecto, le agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: Gracias por respoder amigo, yo tengo organizado el main.storyboard solo con PANTALLA DE INICIO, LOGIN, SIGN UP Y WALKTHROUGH. Al presionar los botones de login y sign up para cambiar a la pantalla home lo tengo asi...

Comment: let mainStoreboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard (name: "Menu", bundle: nil)
        let DVC = mainStoreboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomesViewController") as!
        HomesViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(DVC, animated: true)

Comment: pense que con self.navigationContoller?.pushViewController la pantalla home tendria el nav controller pero no fue asi.

Comment: anexo que en el viewController inicial coloque lo siguiente....  navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    } pero realmente no he logrado encontrar dicha solución, te agradeceria mucho mi amigo si me puedes dar una mano.

Comment: Debes editar la pregunta y ahí colocar el código; se entendería mejor que en la zona de comentarios. Los `ViewController` están embebidos en un `NavigationController`. Estás poniendo `true` para que se oculte?

Comment: Ya hice los ajustes. Si amigo en la primera pantalla de bienvenida oculte con codigo el navigationController en el View Controller asi...

Comment: navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }

Comment: Sin embargo he aplicado el siguiente codigo en varias pantallas y sigue sin aparecer...

Comment: override func viewDisDidDisAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }.         pero tampoco

Comment: Como te mencioné en el comentario, es mejor que edites la pregunta y coloques ahí el código, lo que has intentado y de ser necesario una imagen del resultado actual y del esperado. Insisto, se entendería mejor. No es recomendable llenar la zona de comentarios como si fuera un chat.